# Matching partial expressions between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to perform a partial string match between columns in data frames for example:

df_A:

```
Items_A
purse
string
hat
glue
gum
cherry
cherry
cherry pie
```

and

df_B:

```
1       2    3
string  gum  cherry
glue
```

desired output:

df_matched:

```
matched Items_A
0       purse
1       string
0       hat
1       glue
2       gum
3       cherry
3       cherry
3       cherry pie
```

Note that numbers in the matched columns are the labels from the column that is matched, either 1, 2, or 3.  If there is no match, then the label is 0.

I was able to use Regular expression matching with several nested loops but was wondering if there was a way to use the panda's libraries to perform the operation more efficiently.

Comment: Are multiple matches a possibility? What should happen in such a case?

Comment: multiple matches should have the same label applied, I updated the example based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Reshape df_B to get this :

  ```
     level_0  level_1       0
  0        0        1  string
  1        0        2     gum
  2        0        3  cherry
  3        1        1    glue
  ```
- rename df_B columns
- get the list of unique words in df_B
- create a new column in df_B to find the matching word from df_B in
  df_A
- Merge and filter

> ```
> import regex
>
> df_B = df_B.stack().reset_index()
>
> df_B = df_B.rename(columns={"level_1": "matched", 0: "Items_A"})
>
> items = df_B.Items_A.unique()
>
> def partial_match(x, items):
>     for item in items:
>         if regex.search(r'.?'+item+'.?', x):
>             return item
>     return 0
>
> df_A["matching_item"] = df_A["Items_A"].apply(lambda x: partial_match(x, items))
>
>
> df_A = df_A.merge(df_B, how="left", left_on="matching_item", right_on="Items_A", suffixes=('', '_y'))
>
> df_A = df_A.loc[:,["Items_A", "matched"]]
> ```

Comment: this works if there is an exact match, but not with partial matches.  I will modify the example to reflect this.

Comment: it's been done.   'cherry pie' would match as 'cherry' in the example